# Регулярное выражение для парсинга цены. Парсить товары с ценой выше X

Tags: регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Помогите плз составить выражение регулярное для парсинга. В модуле парсинга есть фильтр. Фильтр проверяет спарсенное значение и если оно подходит, то парсит товар. В этом фильтре можно прописать совпадение по регулярному выражению. Мне нужно спарсить только те товары, которые выше 15000 рублей. Как может выглядеть такое выражение? Значение. по которому идет проверка фильтра без пробелов и знаков, просто цена в виде числа.

Comment: `\d*` Matches zero or more consecutive any decimal digit. Equivalent to [0-9]. Но лучше предоставьте пример значения.

Comment: А почему бы просто не сравнить обычным больше-меньше? использовать регулярное выражение для сравнения двух чисел - это как-то...

Comment: Да вот разработчик модуля не дал такой возможности) Вот так выглядит фильтр - https://ibb.co/0ZXTtJN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярными выражениями пользоваться для диапазона цены не самое лучшее решение. Но если другого выхода нет, то можно попробовать адаптировать вот такой regexp

```
(?(?=^\d{5}$)^(?:1[5-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{3}$|^[1-9]\d{5,}$)
```

Где `(?(?=)|)` некий аналог оператора ветвления по аналогии с if, т.е. если во вложенной скобке выражение истинно, сработает подбор шаблона до пайпа, иначе сработает шаблон после пайпа.
Проверяем что строка у нас равна пяти цифровым символам `^\d{5}$` где `^` - символ начала строки, а `$` - означает конец строки, используется с параметром `multiline`.
Если выражение истинно, то переходи в эту часть `(?:1[5-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{3}$` - начало строки, (цифра 1, после которой идет цифра в диапазоне от 5 до 9 или цифра в диапазоне от 2 до 9, после которой идет любая цифра), 3 любых цифры.
Если выражение было ложно, то переходим в эту часть `^[1-9]\d{5,}$` - начало строки, цифра в диапазоне от 0 до 9, 5 и более цифр в диапазоне от 0 до 5.

---

Важно, минусом данного способа будет то, что в случае если число начинается с 0, то оно автоматически исключается, даже если оно имеет значение выше 15000.

---

Пример работы regexp: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MCV68P/1)

Comment: У вас по моему выполняет слишком много действий выражение.
Посмотрите как выглядит фильтр. То есть он сам определяет ложь или истина, по сути в регулярном выражении нужно указать только то, что истинно. Или нет? Скриншот фильтра - https://ibb.co/99KLSkT

Comment: @Артур, это необходимый минимум действий, под совпадение попадают только значения от 15000 и более, вероятнее всего приложение в котором вы хотите его использовать вряд ли сможет с ним работать. Хорошо бы ссылку на документацию к этому приложению.

Comment: вот непосредственно об этой функции речь https://simplepars.top/index.php?page=note&n=31

Comment: Так как явно используемый движок не указан для reg, попробуйте все таки указать `{reg[#(?(?=^\d{5}$)^(?:1[5-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{3}$|^[1-9]\d{5,}$)#]}`, по идее должно сработать. Понравилась цитата: __Поиск замена полностью поддерживаетрегулярныевыражения.__

Comment: блин, РАБОТАЕТ! Спасибо огромное, проверил на разных ценниках, всё ок.

Comment: @Артур, если ответ помог решить вашу проблему, отметьте его зеленой галочкой

Comment: Но не совсем понял как работает выражение. Если я захочу допустим не от 15т.р. парсить, а от 10000р., то нужно заменить [5-9] на [1-9]? 
почему указано [2-9] после оператора "или" тоже загадка. ОЧЕНЬ СЛОЖНО

Comment: `(?:1[5-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{3})`, т.е. тут выбираем либо первая цифра 1 и далее 5,6,7,8 или 9, либо от 2х до 9 и далее от нуля до 9, а за группой 3 любых числа, если нуно сделать от 10 тысяч, то это будет выглядеть так `(?:[1-9]\d{4})` т.е. от 1 до 9 и далее 4 цифры от 0 до 9. В этом и основная проблема использования регулярных выражений в подобных задачах.

Comment: а зачем от 2х до 9 в этой задаче? Т.е. если первая 1, а потом от 2х до 9, т.е. будет 12000, то оно должно пропускать же?

Comment: Изначально же 15 тысяч было, вот и получается что либо (15,16,17,18,19 | либо от 20 до 99) и далее от 000 до 999. А если от 12 тысяч то да, только тут изменения вносить нужно 1[2-9] вместо 1[5-9]

Comment: в ответе есть ссылка на fiddle, где вы можете в удобной для себя форме отредактировать регулярное  выражение и сразу посмотреть как оно работает

Comment: ааа, всё, понял. я читал как [5-9] или [2-9], а не 1[5-9] или [2-9]/d. Спасибо большое, интересно)